# Container and Row rules in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar under which I want to add some text but the text is always ending up in the navbar area. I made sure all my div tags and ul tags are closed but still no luck..

```
          <!-- CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

          <!-- JS -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

       <style>
       /* Override Some CSS Rules */
       body { background: black; color: green; }
       input[type=text] { color: ligthblue; font-family: "raleway"; background-color: #eee; }
         </style>
        <div id="top"></div>
       </head>
       <body>

       <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> <!-- START: navbar -->
       <div class="container"> <!-- START: container1 -->
       <div class="row"> <!-- START: row1 -->

       <a href="member" class="navbar-brand">Company</a> <!-- Logo -->

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navheader"> <!-- START: navbutton -->
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
                <i class="icon-bar"></i>
            </button> <!-- END: navbutton -->


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navheader"> <!-- START: navheader collapse -->       
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <!-- START: navbar ul class -->

                    <li><a href="member">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#add">Add</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#delete">Remove</a></li>



            </ul> <!-- END: navbar ul class -->
          </div> <!-- END: navheader collapse -->
          </div> <!-- END: row1 -->
          </div> <!-- END: container1 -->
          </div> <!-- END: navbar -->

<!-- This div shows up in navbar area :S -->
       <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
    <font color="green">Hey there!</font>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

       </body>
    </html>
```

Please help. I would like to learn the rules and what I'm doing wrong. Also I want the text centered so is `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">` the best option?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering the text using cols is not a good idea whatsoever. Just use col-md-12, add some other class and set it as text-align:center; As simple as that :D

For your navbar issue - as your menu is fixed, you need to set some padding, as the page itself is behind the fixed element...

```
body {
   padding-top: 50px;

 }
```

Comment: thank you! but what if it's not text but a whole div? Can I still use text-center?

Comment: And doesn't md 12 stretch it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predefined 'text-center' class within Bootstrap to center any text within an element. As for your menu, you'll need to figure out the height of it and add at least that amount in padding to the body. In the example below, the navbar has a height of 51px and the padding on the body is 70px.

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

**Example JSFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/9ba73yhm/3/